How to find an explicit formula for an inverse of a linear operator
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space (with the inner product $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle $), let $x_1,...,x_n$ be a finite sequence of different members of $H$ and let $M:=span\{x_1,...,x_n\}$. It is easy to show that
$$T:M\rightarrow M, T(x):=\sum_{k=1}^n \langle x,x_k\rangle x_k, (x\in M)$$
is a topological isomorphism, where to show that $T$ and the inverse $T^{-1}$ are bounded we do not need an explicit formula for $T$ and $T^{-1}$, since $dim \ M\leq n$.
However, I wonder if one can find an explicit formula for $T^{-1}$, namely, given any $y\in M$, is it possible to solve the equation $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n \langle x,x_k\rangle x_k=y$ for $x$ in order to express $x=T^{-1}y$ explicitly (in terms of, possibly, $y$ and $x_k$)?

Since you are choosing a finite sequence, is this not equivalent to just finding an explicit formula for the inverse of a matrix?

@whpowell96, I think, yes.

Well then, once you have an explicit formula for your matrix use Cramer's Rule.

The operator is of a particular form from which its positive definitnesss follows.

Perhaps it is worthwhile to look for the inverse operator of the same form $\sum_{k=1}^n\langle x,y_k\rangle y_k,$ I would  first  try the case when $x_k$ are linearly indpendent.

Assuming WLOG that $x_k$ are linearly independent, I see that the matrix of $T$ is $(a_{j,k})$, where $a_{j,k}=<x_k,x_j>$, so the trace is $\sum_{j=1}^n||x_j||^2$. And the transpose of the matrix of $T$ is the complex conjugate of the matrix. I don't know if this will be useful

@RyszardSzwarc, By $y_k$ if you mean $S^{-1}(x_k)$, then your formula for the inverse $S^{-1}$ is correct, and this is independent of whether $x_k$'s are linearly independent or not.
